# Adding sub folders in the controller folder - .net webapi

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to add sub folders in the Controller folder of a Webapi project?

I'm thinking of something like Controller/Customer includes the controllers for the Customer module.

Comment: what I want is to have the sub folder name in the URL. i.e: lolcalhost/weApp/{foldername}/{controller}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used areas to solve this problem. As specified here 
http://blogs.infosupport.com/asp-net-mvc-4-rc-getting-webapi-and-areas-to-play-nicely/

Answer (score 6):

Controllers don't work in that way. In Asp.NET your folder structure is your website structure. In WEB API, controllers are looked for independently of the structure. As a matter of fact, you can have them in different assembly and they still will be found by the framework. The routing will not work the way you expect.
You can add a route where you  have your "folder name", like you said,  `localhost/WebApp/{foldername}/{controller}`. Only `{foldername}` can be plain, static folder name (`localhost/WebApp/foldername/{controller}`). So the client will have to call url with "foldername" in it but the location of code wouldn't matter because MVC framework doesn't differentiate folder trees under controllers.

Answer (score 3):

The answers here are wrong. You can easily do this. You just need to then specify the route on your controller class:

Located in `/Controllers/Authentication` folder

```
//An example of you specifying a diff. route than the folder path
[Route("api/login")]
public class LoginController {...}
```

Comment: I think in your example here, it should be `[RoutePrefix("api/login")]` and not `[Route(...)]`. The `[Route(...)]` attribute would go onto individual actions inside the `LoginController` class.

Answer (score 2):

What I do to solve this issue for my self is adding another Maproute and add namespace before the controller. Just be aware of two points:

1. Your new rout should be before the Default one
2. You cannot add the namespace for the default one

   ```
       routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Secretariat",
          url: "{namespace}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
   ```